# Using Rake, that loads my db from a YAML file, can i set environments?

Tags: ruby, rake

My database.yml looks like:

```
adapter: mysql
database: my_db
username: user1
password: '123'
host: localhost
```

This is a non-rails application, just using rake/ruby for some scripting.

Can I set a default (dev) and production in this yaml file, or is that rails specific?

If yes, when running something like:

rake user:create

How do I pass in if it is production and therefore use the production db settings in the yaml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you read the yaml file into memory and parse it is a good place to put the logic to use the current environment (or a default if none is set). A simple way to do this is to rely on an environment variable (don't use RAILS_ENV if it's not a rails app, or RACK_ENV if it's not a rack app).

Use something like:

```
my_env = ENV['MY_ENV_VARIABLE'] || 'development'
db_settings = YAML::load(File.open(yml_file))[my_env]
```

Then you can call rake via:

```
MY_ENV_VARIABLE=production rake my_task
```

Or if you want to add a param to the task itself, you can set it up to use

```
rake my_task[production]
```

(but that can get messy depending on if you have to quote the whole thing, like in zsh).

Another approach that some libraries use (like heroku_san) is to have a separate task that sets the environment variable, and rely on calling multiple tasks, so you'd have a task `:production` that sets the environment variable and can then call

```
rake production my_task
```

Comment: thanks, but then I have the issue of that envir being set, and available for whatever user is running in the current context.  i'd rathe rjust pass in a parameter to the rake call, possible?

Comment: I would decouple this from rake as much as possible. I would keep the env var in case the code is called through some other mechanism than rake, and then just have rake set the same one. You still have coupling, but it's connascence of name.

Comment: I updated the answer to give some suggestions for incorporating rake